# Make game panel

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, viewport

1 )I am currently making 2d tank game. I need to make panel where I could draw information about tanks etc. What is the best way to do that? Do I need to make 2 viewports (1 for game and 1 for panel) or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a fixed area to show the information within your gui/hud. Or you could popup the text when you hover over a text. So locate where the mouse is at and if it hovers over a sprite start drawing the text at the cursor location.